# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\backend\BrandController] does not exist. i am using Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i upload my project in hostinger host but after that when i try to go anywhere in admin Dahsboard show me that controller Doesn,t exist but in localhost works fine

here is the error in each controller I got Like That

```
 Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

Target class [App\Http\Controllers\backend\BrandController] does not exist.

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:835
```

**i have tried solve this error by this code but doesn't work**

in RouteServiceProvider.php

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

   
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
```

Comment: I think you use Microsoft Windows. The windows reads the names of the folders in case-sensitively, but Linux is case-sensitive.
I think your folder name is 'Backend'.

Comment: you are  correct thank you